# Query DB using apex in salesforce

Tags: apex-code, force.com

com and apex triggers

I have two objects namely **Customer_c** and **Order_c**
I am trying to write a trigger to delete an order entry belonging to a customer who has been made inactive.

Basically i want to trigger on update for **customer_c** table

retrieve an entry from **customer_c** where the **Active_c**( boolean value) has been made false upon update  and take that customers '**Name**' and look up in the **Order_c** table and delete all the **'Name'(Orders**) belonging to that customer.

Below is my trigger code. when I am trying to save the trigger in salesforce.
I get the following error:

```
Error: Compile Error: unexpected token: 'res2' at line 13 column 19
```

Could anyone please help me on this?

```
trigger NewCustomerActive on Customer__c(after update) {
  List<Customer__c> res2 = 
        [SELECT Name FROM Customer__c j WHERE j.Active__c = false];
  List<Order__c> res = 
        [SELECT Name FROM Order__c WHERE Customer__c = res2];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change it to

```
trigger NewCustomerActive on Customer__c(after update) {
  List<Customer__c> res2 = 
        [SELECT Name FROM Customer__c j WHERE j.Active__c = false];
  List<Order__c> res = 
        [SELECT Name FROM Order__c WHERE Customer__c in:res2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to save soql statements:

```
trigger NewCustomerActive on Customer__c(after update) {
  List<Order__c> res = 
        [SELECT Name FROM Order__c WHERE Customer__r.Active__c = false];
}
```